# How to replaces file with existing file and deleting original file?

Tags: c#, replacewith

I need to do in c# ability to replace file with existing file and deleting original file.
This is my current code and this code does not replace file with same name:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateUploadedFiles();
        }
    }

    private void PopulateUploadedFiles()
    {
        using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            List<UploadedFile> allFiles = dc.UploadedFiles.ToList();
            DataListOktobar.DataSource = allFiles;
            DataListOktobar.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void BtnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

            using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
            {

                dc.UploadedFiles.Add(
                    new UploadedFile
                    {
                        FileName = file.FileName,
                        ContentType = file.ContentType,
                        FileID = 0,
                        FileSize = file.ContentLength,
                        FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName),
                        FileContent = buffer
                    });
                dc.SaveChanges();
                PopulateUploadedFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for replace algorithm:

1. search for existing file with the same name as the uploaded file, if you find such file, delete it
2. add a new file

One thing to consider is, whether your DB is case sensitive when searching for a file with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for help Martin Staufcik